# Python modbus communcation reading words on Mitsubishi Q03udv PLC using ModbusTcpClient library

Tags: python, modbus

Python `modbus` communcation reading words on `Mitsubishi PLC` using `ModbusTcpClient` library

How to read data register `D1` `DE` or else

I have tested it ....Connection is fine but reading give error .Incomplete message received.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('10.1.1.4',port=5007)
client.connect()

result = client.read_holding_registers(1,1)
print result
t = result.registers[0]
print t
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Connection is successful, but Unable to find address of D1, D2 or else.  
while reading using client.read_holding_registers(1,1)   , getting empty result.

Comment: Try passing the unit address as part of your request `result = client.read_holding_registers(1,1, unit=<unit-address>)`

Comment: Have tried the Same, Actually I need to read D1 , D2 and such Registers,  and I dont know the address for the same, and also How to know the exact unit address.   
My PLC is Q03UDVCPU  of mitsubishi.